# Smalltalk Input/Output

Tags: smalltalk

I am having trouble regarding Smalltalk. I am attempting to populate an array with the numbers that are read from the file, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried numerous options and I was hoping someone would explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
 Object subclass: #MyStack
        instanceVariableNames:'anArray aStack'
        classVariableNames:''
        poolDictionaries:''

!
MyStack class comment: 'Creates a Stack Class.'
!

!
MyStack methodsFor: 'initialize Stack'
!

new "instance creation"
        ^ super new.
!
init "initialization"
        anArray := Array new: 32.
        aStack := 0.
! !

!MyStack methodsFor: 'methods for stacks' !


pop "Removes the top entry from the stack"
    | item |
    item := anArray at: aStack.
    aStack := aStack - 1.
!

push: x "Pushes a new entry onto the stack"
    aStack := aStack + 1.
    anArray at:aStack put:x.
!

top "Returns the current top of the stack"
        ^anArray at: aStack.
!

empty "True if the stack is empty"
        ^aStack = 0.
!

full "True if the stack is full"
        ^aStack = 32.
!

printOn: aStream "Prints entire stack one entry per line, starting the top entry"
    aStream show: 'Stack:'.
    aStack to:1 by:-1 do:[:i |(anArray at:i) printOn:aStream. ].
    aStream show: ''
! !
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Object subclass: #IOExample
  instanceVariableNames: 'input output'
  classVariableNames: ''
  poolDictionaries: ''
!
IOExample class comment: '
 basic I/O.
'
!

!
IOExample methodsFor: 'initialize'
!
new
  ^ super new.

!
init
  [ input := FileSelectionBrowser open asFilename readStream. ]
    on: Error
    do: [ :exception |
      Dialog warn: 'Unable to open file'.
      exception retry.
    ].
  [ output := FileSelectionBrowser open asFilename writeStream. ]
    on: Error
    do: [ :exception |
      Dialog warn: 'Unable to open file'.
      exception retry.
    ].

! !

!
IOExample methodsFor: 'copy input to output turning :: into :'
!
copy
  | data lookAhead theStack myStack|
  [ input atEnd ] whileFalse: [

    data := input next.
    (data isKindOf: Integer)
      ifTrue: [
        (input atEnd) ifFalse: [
        "myStack push: data."
        lookAhead = input peek.
        (lookAhead asCharacter isDigit)
            ifTrue: [
            ]              
        ].
      ].  
    output show: myStack.



  ].
  input close.
  output close.
! !
```

Comment: A few things: 1) please specify which dialect of Smalltalk you are using (I tried to file in your code into `Pharo`, which doesn't have `#subclass:instanceVariableNames:classVariableNames:poolDictionaries:` 2) It's not common practice to share code in chunk format. It's difficult to read and requires someone to copy/paste into a text file to load 3) You didn't provide details about the input file

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to run this code? If you did, I'm surprised you didn't get a compilation warning due to #2 below.

There are a number of problems in `#copy` (besides the fact that I don't understand exactly what it's trying to do)...

1. First you seems to expect the data to be numbers: `data isKindOf: Integer`. But then later you treat it as a stream of Characters: `lookAhead asCharacter isDigit`. If the first condition is true to get you past that point, the second one never can be, as you would've matched [0-9], which aren't ASCII values for digits.
2. `lookAhead = input peek`. Here you're comparing uninitialized `lookAhead` (`nil`) with the peeked value, and then throwing away the result. I assume you meant `lookAhead := input peek`.
3. Then there is the empty inner condition `ifTrue: [ ]`. What are you trying to do there?
4. Then there's the odd protocol name, 'copy input to output turning :: into :'. What does that mean, and what does that have to do with copying numbers between streams?

Comment: Thank you. I know I wasn't very informative, but I have fixed the problem I had asked.

Answer (score 2):

Justin, let me try to help you with the class `MyStack` and defer to another answer any comments on your example.

I've divided your code into fragments and appended my comments.

---

**Fragment A:**

```
Object subclass: #MyStack
    instanceVariableNames:'anArray aStack'
    classVariableNames:''
    poolDictionaries:''
```

*Comments for A:*

A Smalltalker would have used instance variable names without indeterminate articles `a` or `an`

```
Object subclass: #MyStack
    instanceVariableNames:'array stack'
    classVariableNames:''
    poolDictionaries:''
```

---

**Fragment B:**

```
MyStack class comment: 'Creates a Stack Class.'
```

*Comments for B:*

This is weird. I would have expected this instead (with no `class`):

```
MyStack comment: 'Creates a Stack Class.'
```

---

**Fragment C:**

```
MyStack methodsFor: 'initialize Stack'

new "instance creation"
    ^ super new.
```

Comments for C:*

This code puts `new` on the instance side of the class, which makes no sense because you usually send `new` to the class rather than its instances. The correct form requires adding `class`:

```
MyStack class methodsFor: 'initialize Stack'

new
    ^super new.
```

You forgot to send the initialization method (however, see Fragment D below)

```
new
    ^super new init.
```

---

**Fragment D:**

```
init "initialization"
    anArray := Array new: 32.
    aStack := 0.
```

*Comments for D:*

In Smalltalk people use the selector `initialize` so it can send super first

```
initialize
    super initialize.
    array := Array new: 32.
    stack := 0.
```

Note that this change would require also writing `new` as

```
new
    ^super new initialize.
```

However, if your dialect already sends the `initialize` method by default, you should remove the implementation of `new` from your class.

---

**Fragment E:**

```
pop "Removes the top entry from the stack"
    | item |
    item := anArray at: aStack.
    aStack := aStack - 1.
```

*Comments for E:*

You forgot to answer the `item` just popped out

```
pop
    | item |
    item := array at: stack.
    stack := stack - 1.
    ^item
```

---

**Fragment F:**

```
push: x "Pushes a new entry onto the stack"
    aStack := aStack + 1.
    anArray at:aStack put:x.
```

*Comments for F:*

This is ok. Note however that the stack will refuse to push any item beyond the limit of 32.

```
push: x
    stack := stack + 1.
    array at: stack put: x.
```

---

**Fragment G:**

```
top "Returns the current top of the stack"
    ^anArray at: aStack.

empty "True if the stack is empty"
    ^aStack = 0.

full "True if the stack is full"
    ^aStack = 32.
```

*Comments for G:*

These are ok too. However, a more appropraite name for `empty` would have been `isEmpty` because all collections understand this polymorphic message. Similarly, the recommended selector for `full` would be `isFull`:

```
top
    ^array at: aStack.

isEmpty
    ^stack = 0.

isFull
    ^stack = 32.
```

Note also that `isFull` repeats the magic constant 32, which you used in the initialization code. That's not a good idea because if you change your mind in the future and decide to change 32 with, say, 64 you will have to modify two methods an not just one. You can eliminate this duplication in this way

```
isFull
    ^stack = array size.
```

---

**Fragment H:**

```
printOn: aStream
    "Prints entire stack one entry per line, starting the top entry"
    aStream show: 'Stack:'.
    aStack to:1 by:-1 do:[:i |(anArray at:i) printOn:aStream. ].
    aStream show: ''
```

*Comments for H:*

The last line of this code is superfluous and I would get rid of it. However, you may want to separate every item from the next with a space

```
printOn: aStream
    stream show: 'Stack:'.
    stack to: 1 by: -1 do:[:i |
        aStream space.
        (array at: i) printOn: aStream].
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very informative. However, the names I have chosen are mandatory due to the guidelines given to me.

Comment: @JustinB123 No problem. You can use the names given to you. Just remember that those names are not the ones that a Smalltalker would use. Actually, the ivar  `stack` is misleading too because that variable keeps track of where the top of stack is and should be named `top`.

Comment: I have run into a problem, but I had fixed my earlier. I am afraid of posting the entire code on the internet since it will be for a grade eventually. Is there any way I can show you my code privately? The problem has to do with adding rational numbers, the dialect of Smalltalk is SmallTalk/X. When I attempt to find the remainder of two numbers(both have a denominator of 1), it says that it doesn't understand the remainder operation. I'm not sure why it's having a problem and my colleague doesn't either.
@Leandro Caniglia

Comment: @JustinB123 Try to isolate the piece of code that is not working for you and paste it in a new Question here at StackOverflow. Remember to tag it as Smalltalk and to mention that you are using Smalltalk/X (BTW it is Smalltalk with lowercase t)